# Error In Deploying LWC

Tags: deployment, lightning-web-components, scratch-org

I'm trying to deploy my code but when It's not updated in custom components

Kindly advice what's the issue and can you advice also the difference between working on scratch orgs and non-scratch orgs with lightning web component

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its says to enable my domain? have you done that?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me :)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

probably it's already irrelevant, but still. App Builder points out that you don't have My Domain deployed and it's required in order to use Custom Lightning Components. So please deploy it in Setup -> My Domain and then you'll be able to see your component

Answer (score 0):

There's no errors, so presumably, you just need to update your metadata.

Locate the file helloWebComponent.js-meta.xml, and alter it to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets> 
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

You'll want to check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_meta_file), including the "See Also" sections.

As for your final question, there is no difference with LWC in regards to using scratch orgs versus not. The only general difference is that you can't use force:source:push on a non-scratch org, nor force:source:pull.

Comment: It's already updated                                                                                                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWebComponent"> but still same issue